# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.AndroidGradleModel

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.AndroidGradleModelexception** when I run my plugin on Android Studio. When I run plugin on Intellij IDEA all ok, plugin works.
Full sample you can find on this [repo](https://github.com/landarskiy/sample-android-studio-plugin)
My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-plugin-service' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.org.jetbrains.intellij.plugins:gradle-intellij-plugin:0.2.11"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.intellij" version "0.2.11"
}

apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.intellij"
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

intellij {
    version 'IC-2016.2'
    plugins = ['android', 'gradle']
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
}
```